# Calculation with operators

Tags: c++

I know this looks like homework, but it isn't.

> Please develop a program which could take in 5 ints (from 1 to 9), and use +, -, *, /, (, ) these operators to calculate at least one equation to make the result = 24. The operators, you do not need to use all of them, and also, you could use each of them as many times as you want.
>
> For example, if user put in 3, 8, 1, 1, 1 to your program, the result should be:
>
> 3 * 8 / 1 / 1 / 1 = 24

I don't want the actual solution to this, but could someone please give me some starting tips?

Comment: How can it not be homework? Please xplain.

Comment: *I know this looks like homework, but it isn't.* -- "Homework" doesn't necessarily mean it was assigned to you by a teacher.  Self-assignments where you're asking us to look for a solution is also considered homework.

Comment: Looks like an online judge or contest problem.

Comment: I just wish there were a shortcut to "vote to close, since it's homework"

Comment: Take 5 integers and draw a tree.  For example, start with 5.  Use 4 branches, for +, -, /, and *.  At the end of the branches, place the next digit.  Figure out either how to construct the tree or traverse it.

Comment: "Since it's homework" would be abused. Some homework questions are fine. This is a zero effort question, and those are not fine.

Answer (score 4):

> could someone please give me some starting tips?

**Tip #1:Get started.** It doesn't matter that you don't know how to write this program, just write the simplest program you can to get started and then build from there. You can write Hello World, right? Do that. Do you know how to accept input from the user? Add that. Building a program that can accept input and print output will get you significantly further than you are now.

**Tip #2: Break it down.** Instead of worrying about how to accept five integers and operators, can you do two? Or maybe just accept two integers and print their sum to start. Once you're that far, you'll have a much better sense of what you'd need to do to accept operators and more numbers.

**Tip #3: Ask for help (at the right time).** Right now, you don't have anything done at all, so everything seems overwhelming. You can't even sort out what you know from what you don't know, so you don't know enough to ask a good question. Once you get started, you'll start to home in on the things you really don't know. Those things will be much better defined at that point, and you'll be able to do a more focussed search for solutions. Chances are, someone has already asked questions about the same things you don't understand, and you'll be able to find those questions once you know what to focus on. If not, you'll be able to ask a much more specific question that provides enough details to let someone help you. Those are exactly the kinds of questions that tend to get up votes and good answers, and (more importantly) really help you learn something.

**Tip #4: Forget the computer.** Try solving the problem with index cards, where each card represents some piece of data, like a number or an operator. Sometimes this helps you see how the data should be organized in order to solve the problem. Solving a problem in the real world helps you develop a mental model for solving it in code.